# Does the following converge uniformly?

Tags: uniform-convergence

Does $$f_n(x)=\frac{nx}{1+n(1+x^2)}$$ converge uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$?  To what?  Justify.

Comment: Is the function bounded?

Comment: @newbie Yes. Divide top and bottom by $n$.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff that's a hint...

Comment: First instinct is to find where it could "break" so I took the derivative and set it to zero and solved.

Comment: @newbie How is it a hint?

Comment: @PeterTamaroff Well...To investigate if a sequence of functions converges, there are several behoviors worth of attention: unboundedness, fluctuations and shifted extreme value (the preimage of extreme value depending on $n$), etc. Boundedness would be the first thing to check. And since this sequence well behaves, we are confident to guess it is uniformly convergent.

Answer (score 4):

Note that $${f_n}(x) = \frac{x}{{\frac{1}{n} + 1 + {x^2}}}$$

Can you work something out now? Note that the pointwise limit is $$f(x)=\frac{x}{1+x^2}$$ and that $$\begin{align}
  \left| {f(x) - {f_n}(x)} \right| &= \left| {\frac{x}{{\left( {1 + {x^2}} \right)\left( {1 + n\left( {1 + {x^2}} \right)} \right)}}} \right| \\ 
   &\leqslant \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{{1 + n\left( {1 + {x^2}} \right)}}\\
   &\leqslant \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{{n\left( {1 + {x^2}} \right)}} \\ 
   &\leqslant \frac{1}{{2n}} \end{align} $$

because $\dfrac{x}{1+x^2}$ is at most $1/2$ and $\dfrac{1}{1+x^2}$ is at most $1$ over the real line.